# Error Viewing HTML5 code in Eclipse Neon with subclipse and Aptana plugins

Tags: eclipse, html, aptana3

I've done a fresh install of Eclipse Neon, then installed subclipse, (successfully) imported a project from SVN, then installed the Aptana plugin (purely to have integrated sftp support). (These are all the very latest versions). When I attempt to open an html file, it fails to open and I get blank tabs where the filename would normally occur within eclipse. I've uninstalled and reinstalled numerous times with the same effect. There seems to be no updates or anything addressing this. I get various errors ranging from Null Pointer exceptions to Wordwrap errors. I've used the error reporting feature to report this bug to eclipse. This can be viewed here:
https://dev.eclipse.org/recommenders/community/aeri/v2/#!/submissions/gKGfmAiOTc7a1rLDYWpaRfpy7wE4EKDs1Co4OlqRpg7vpHKlOmVsD1YdyjNNbKVO. Has anyone got any clue about this please?

Comment: Which Neon install/download is this? Which editor is it trying to open? You can double-check from the file's context menu's `Open With` submenu.

Comment: Hi.  This is the latest 64Bit executable downloadable from the eclipse download page. Release 4.6.0. Build Id 20160613-1800. Last downloaded 25/07/2016. it's using the default HTML editor. Apatana Studio 3 Core version 4.4.0.1444271068B.  Aptana Studio 3 Core 4.4.0.1444271068-B37f83CK1vbz-cz-RUr983335598 com.aptana.feature.feature.group Aptana.  Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.7.0.201510080322-7g7B37jBYcjqMJaO8SuJ8sU2whLv.  I suspect it might be using the Aptana HTML editor(??)

Comment: Couldn't get Eclipse Neon to work with this setup unfortunately.  Reverted to Eclipse Mars and all worked perfectly first time without a hitch. I think I'll stick with this until Eclipse/Aptana sort out that issue.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with JavaScript files.

Comment: I can verify this behavior with Eclipse Neon.2 and Aptana 4.9.0 on the Mac. Annoying and reverting to Mars. An FTP plugin like Aptana is awesome. Too bad I can't run it in Neon.